Limit of upper triangular matrix is zero
I am working on this problem.
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be an upper triangular matrix and suppose that for $i = 1, \dots, n$, $|a_{ii}| < 1$. Show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k = 0$.
What I have done is the following. Let $k = mn$. Then $\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k = \lim_{m \to \infty} A^{mn} = (\lim_{m \to \infty} A^m)^n = 0$, because the limit will give me a strictly upper triangular matrix due to $|a_{ii}| < 1$, and strictly upper triangular matrices are nilpotent. Is this correct? There must be a better solution. Any help is appreciated.

Techincally, this only proves that if the limit exists, then it is zero: while it is true that $[A^m]{ii}\to 0$ for all $i$, you haven't proved that $[A^m]{ij}$ converges for $j>i$.

I see. But then it seems I don't have enough information to conclude the limit exists. There will we entries that won't be multiplied by the diagonal entries and hence won't be bounded in any way.

The usual idea would be to exploit the existence of a matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is in Jordan normal form and then calculate the powers of each Jordan block directly (namely, for $j>i$, $(J(\lambda,k)^m)_{ij}=\lambda^{m-j+i}\binom m{j-i}\stackrel{m\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0$ because $j-i<k$ and $\binom m{j-i}$ is a polynomial in $m$ of degree $< k$).

Can I assume there is a Jordan form if $A$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

@user123456 If the matrix is triangulable (which it is because it is triangular already), then yes. A matrix $X$ is tirangulable in $\Bbb F^{n\times n}$ if and only if the following equivalent conditions are met: 1) there is some $P\in GL(n,\Bbb F)$ such that $PXP^{-1}$ is upper triangular; 2) there is some $P\in GL(n,\Bbb F)$ such that $PXP^{-1}$ is lower triangular; 3) all the roots of $\det(A-tI)$ are in $\Bbb F$.

There are other ways to see things. A low(er)-tech one could be to call $H_{ii}=\max\limits_i \lvert a\rvert_{ii}$, $H_{ij}=\max\limits_{h<k} \lvert a\rvert_{hk}$ if $i<j$ and $0$ if $i>j$, then prove that $\lvert [A^m]{ij}\rvert\le \lvert [H^m]{ij}\rvert$, then prove that $H^m\to 0$. That's because $H=\lambda I+N$ with $N$ nilpotent, therefore, for $m\ge n$, $H^m=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \lambda^{m-j}\binom mjN^j$.

I will try this second thing. Thank you.

It is equivalent to prove each column $A^k e_j$ of $A^k$ goes to $0$. Set
\begin{eqnarray*}
  c & = & \sup_{1 \leq i \leq n}  | a_{i i} |\\
  & < & 1.
\end{eqnarray*}
For $k \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  A^k e_1 & = & a_{1 1}^k e_1,\\
  A^k e_2 & = & A^{k - 1}  (a_{1 2} e_1 + a_{2 2} e_2)\\
  & = & a_{1 2} a_{1 1}^{k - 1} e_1 + a_{2 2} A^{k - 1} e_2,\\
  \| A^k e_2 \| & \leq & | a_{1 2} | c^{k - 1} + c \| A^{k - 1} e_2 \|\\
  & \leq & | a_{1 2} | c^{k - 1} + | a_{1 2} | c^{k - 1} + c^2  \| A^{k - 2}
  e_2 \|\\
  & \leq & \ldots\\
  & \leq & k | a_{1 2} | c^{k - 1} + c^k .
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $A^k e_1 \rightarrow 0$ and $A^k e_2 \rightarrow 0$. Similar estimates
can show that $A^k e_j \rightarrow 0$ for $j = 3, \ldots, n$.

Wouldn't there be a problem when you take the limit as $k \to \infty$? The right hand side of the last inequality depends directly on $k$.

@user123456 Yeah it goes to $0$ as $k \to \infty$. For any $p > 0$, $k^p c^k \to 0$.
